# Getting ambiguous error when calling Input.GetTouch(0).position in Unity

Tags: android, vector, input, unity-game-engine, touch

Im using this code to get the direction of a throw:

```
throwDirection = -(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hookedObject.transform.position) - 
Input.mousePosition)/(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hookedObject.transform.position) - 
Input.mousePosition).magnitude;
```

My problem is when i try to translate this to work with touch, it gives me this error:

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: UnityEngine.Vector2.operator -(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2) and UnityEngine.Vector3.operator -(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)

Here is the touch version of the code, it basically just replaces `Input.mousePosition` with `Input.GetTouch(0).position`:

```
throwDirection = -(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hookedObject.transform.position) - 
Input.GetTouch(0).position)/(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hookedObject.transform.position)
- Input.GetTouch(0).position).magnitude;
```

Im confused why this error is occuring. Im using a vector2 for the mouse position, and a vector 2 for the touch positions. Yet this error only occurs on the touch version of the code? It appears twice for everytime i try to use `Input.GetTouch(0).position`.

When i try to save `Input.GetTouch(0).position` to a variable the same error occurs. But it only occurs when i use the variable, not when i store the variable.

For instance:

```
Vector2 touchPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
```

This doesnt give me the error however if i try to use this variable in another statement, the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hookedObject.transform.position is Vector3 while Input.GetTouch(0).position is Vector2.

mousePosition is actually also Vector3 which is why that code did work.

It is possible to cast Vector2 to Vector3 and vice versa which is why its ambiguous. Casting touch to Vector3 should fix your problem.

```
    throwDirection = -
(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hookedObject.transform.position) - (Vector3)
Input.GetTouch(0).position)/(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hookedObject.transform.position)
- (Vector3)Input.GetTouch(0).position).magnitude;
```

Comment: Casting it to vector3 definitely gets rid of the error im having but im confused, if Input.mousePosition is a Vector3 what information does Z contain? throwDirection is actually a Vector2 i thought i was dealing with all vector2s, my raycasting is off because of this.

Comment: Casting from Vector2 to Vector3 sets z to 0, and from Vector3 to Vector2 it just discards the z. So if you just need to position on the screen you can cast amera.main.WorldToScreenPoint to a Vector2.

Answer (score 0):

- [`Input.GetTouch(0).position`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html) is a Vector2.
- [`Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) is a Vector3.

So your Vector3 - Vector2 is impossible. You can substract a Vector3 to another Vector3, or a Vector2 to another Vector2, but not mix them.

You can allocate a new Vector2 taking the Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint x and y, and then substract your vectors.